# I have no idea about how the following lines ended up in my root's .bash_history?

Tags: root, gnupg, bash-history

```
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
Version: GnuPG v1.4.11 (GNU/Linux)

iJwEAQEKAAYFAlb7STMACgkQh7sHtMmeQOHEcQQAorwdGYtbPMN8aS5hM0hvhy+O
s7vxpbSdfvKHVskYUiml0UvC3zhA3cyqMjiKHpnOR4Zhaq4esrPcbHQSzJbn4vGn
lW2+YLR6T//l3TkUnSQTpzBBm7W42EBUYYp7iwHSCfuoTnswF1JAOcy1bF4R9S1/
HRxa9V486bwVsrQ2cgI=
=mb8Y
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----
\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00
```

I did not use any gpg/pgp encrypt/decrypt during the time line of that entry, after shutting down on previous night and booting the pc the following morning I found some new entries in the root's history that is not done by me.